# Get not all values but specific values of field in another model with one to one field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models.
1. courses
2. First Year

Here is course Model

```
class Courses(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Courses'

    year_choices = [
        ('----', '----'),
        ('First Year', 'First Year'),
        ('Second Year', 'Second Year'),
        ('Third Year', 'Third Year'),
        ('Fourth Year', 'Fourth Year'),
        ('Minor', 'Minor'),
    ]
    year = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='----',choices=year_choices)
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                               default='',
                               validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
```

Here is FirstYear Model

```
class FirstYear(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = '1. First Year'

    course   = models.OneToOneField(Courses,
                                    default='',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title).capitalize()
```

I'm new to Django. My question is I have to invoke the course_code field only if it is first year and not all year.

```
Example : Course Model
object-1 -> year = First Year
            course_code = HJK456
object-2 -> year = Second Year
            course_code = ERT890
```

Here I Have to get HJK456 in onetoone field only, not ERT890. I should display only the option choosed as first year. Help me how to filter.

Please help me here. Thank you.

Comment: What code do you run? You only included the models declaration. You should also include the view and serializer.

Comment: I don't include view because this is only for admin so they can go to the admin panel and do add something.

Comment: So you want to obtain all the courses for the FirstYear?
Do you have the option to change the models relation a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `limit_choices_to` argument to restrict the options displayed in the admin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

```
class FirstYear(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = '1. First Year'

    course = models.OneToOneField(Courses,
                                  default='',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  limit_choices_to={'year': 'First Year'})
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
```